# Angularjs datatable createdRow add class to specific row

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using angularjs datatables. I would like to add custom class to row if some condition true.
This is how a tried:

```
this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
...
.withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
   if (data.highlight) {
      let el = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'tr:nth-child('+dataIndex+')' ) )
      el.addClass('highlight');
   }
 })
...
```

data.highlight is true for some row, so the condition is ok, but the addClass is not working.

Comment: Was the answer not useful? This is exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular way you can do like this.

```
   .withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
      if (data.highlight) {
        angular.element( row ).addClass('highlight');
      }
   })
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need such complicated construct. Since you are using dataTables you do have jQuery available :

```
if (data.highlight) {
  $( row ).addClass('highlight');
}
```

would be sufficient.